# count is not incrementing within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created an application in angularjs, here i am having a table which i am trying to put a dynamic id, where the dynamic id is generated within the ng-init in an hyperlink, the application is working fine but the count is not incrementing

can anyone please tell some solution for this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g24tp0op/)**

```
<div ng-app="Test1">
    <div ng-controller="Foo">
      <span ng-repeat="section in sectionData.sections">
       <span ng-repeat="regions in section.regions">
         <span ng-repeat="places in regions.places">
             <a ng-init="count++" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getClick(count)">Click</a>
                <table id="{{count}}" border="1">
                      <tr><td>{{places.placeName}}</td></tr>
                </table>
         </span>
        </span> 
       </span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directive which keeps track in a closure of the global count and expose the unique id incremented every time the link function runs to the scope.

```
directive('uniqueId',function(){

    var count=0;

    return {
        scope:{
            uniqueId:'='
        },
        link:function(scope, element, attr){
         count+=1;
        scope.uniqueId=count;
        }
    };
});
```

and the markup

```
<a unique-id="places.id" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getClick(places.id)">Click</a>
```

see this [running example](http://jsfiddle.net/un5fyh6g/)

Comment: change {{count}} by {{places.id}} on the id attribute of your table elements

Answer (score 1):

Does the id need to be an int?

```
<div ng-app="Test1">
    <div ng-controller="Foo">
      <span ng-repeat="section in sectionData.sections" ng-init="id1 = $index">
       <span ng-repeat="regions in section.regions"  ng-init="id2 = id1 + '-' + $index">
         <span ng-repeat="places in regions.places" ng-init="id3 = id2 + '-' + $index">
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getClick(id3)">Click</a>
                <table id="{{id3}}" border="1">
                      <tr><td>{{places.placeName}}</td></tr>
                </table>
         </span>
        </span> 
       </span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ng-init="count" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getClick(count)">Click</a>
            <table id="{{count = count+1}}" border="1">
                  <tr><td>{{places.placeName}}</td></tr>
            </table>
```

try this one not sure

Comment: nope i want a unique dynamic id, you cant specify $index

Comment: Make it useful depending on $index. For example, if you want like 101, 102, 103.. then you can pass getClick($index + 101)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `count` to `$index`

```
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getClick($index)">Click</a>
            <table id="{{$index}}" border="1">
                  <tr><td>{{places.placeName}}</td></tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: see i want unique id, if you see there place 1 and place 3 will be having same index when you click http://jsfiddle.net/g24tp0op/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could always get rid of `ng-init="count++"` and replace `{{count}}` with `{{getUniqueIndex()}}`. In your controller scope you would define a function `getUniqueIndex` which returns what you need.  This has the additional benefit of keeping that logic in the controller where you are probably using it more anyway.

Comment: but how to assign to table id, since there will be multiple tables right

Comment: You would need to keep track of them in your model. One idea would be a 2D array.